# How to run .sql files in vscode on .csv files

Tags: database, sqlite, csv

How do I run .sql files in vscode on .csv files?

Tried all extensions, I dont want to use a database

I just want to run my .sql file and the query to get data from the .csv file

I want to do something like this?

-- SELECT id
-- FROM document.csv
-- WHERE id_name = 'John';

Thanks :)

Comment: sql files run of sql server server csv files can be open by diverse programs including sql servers, so you would import the data into a server and then run the query

Comment: Rainbow CSV has an extension that allows simple "querying" of csv files in VSCode. But I'd advise you to keep an eye out for other ways to work with csv data as there are many many ways of doing this and many of them have their various pros and cons. A five whys approach might help here ... "why do you want to query csv in vscode" .... and for that answer, ask why do you want to .... and so on ... ! The idea is to figure out what it is you "really" need to do! For instance, if you are saying you want to use sql without using a database ... why do you want to use SQL, and why you not want a DB.